# auctex output in shell

Tags: auctex, output

How to redirect the AUCTeX output to the shell buffer (M-x shell) of emacs? (= use a shell buffer instead of the AUCTeX output buffer). This way one could seamlessly combine (LaTeX) shell commands and AUCTeX commands, and got also the history of outputs at ones disposal. (I know this feature from other TeX shells).

Comment: Can you post your current buffer?  I am not sure what you want in your buffer.  For instance, my buffer post my whole `.log` file when I compile.  Does yours not and that is what you want?

Comment: My issue is interactivity, not the completeness of the log. I.e., the output buffer should be an interactive shell buffer into which the Latex command is piped. Currently the shell is running in the background and only the output is mirrored in the output buffer.

Comment: @Benno do you just want to run the TeX processor interactively?  In that case you only need to add this to your `.emacs`: `(setq TeX-interactive-mode t)`.

Comment: By this option (C-c C-t C-i) I get only the output window, which allows no input and I see no interactivity. In fact, when using emacs without the auctex package but only with its basic (La)Tex-mode, an interactive tex-shell is always there, allowing arbitrary shell input and "endless" history (the shell). I'm looking for this under auctex.